# Flash - Get links URL from external XML/TXT file

Tags: flash, actionscript

**Hello,**

I bought a flash template who uses this code for links in the header

```
onClipEvent (load) {
    num = 2;
    _parent.ti1.gotoAndStop(num);
    _parent.ti2.gotoAndStop(num);
}
on (rollOver) {
    if (_root.link<>num) {
    _parent.gotoAndPlay("s1");
    }
}
on (releaseOutside, rollOut) {
    if (_root.link<>num) {
    _parent.gotoAndPlay("s2");  
    }
}
on (release) {
    if (_root.link<>num) {
        _root.link_prev = _root.link;
        _parent._parent["item"+_root.link].gotoAndPlay("s2");
        _root.link = num;
        getURL("./page-name/");
    }
}
```

What I want is to be able to modify the page URL from an external file (xml or txt). I want just an external file, and here, on the AS of the button to modify just the line number of where to get the link from external file.

**Thank you**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash can read variables from text files. However, if the text file is on a different domain than the site you are hosting the swf, you need to place a crossdomain.xml file on the root of the domain containing the text file.

```
onClipEvent (load) {
    num = 2;
    _parent.ti1.gotoAndStop(num);
    _parent.ti2.gotoAndStop(num);
    this.loadVariables("external.txt");
}
```

The text file called external.txt could be:

```
&goToUrl=urlHere
```

And then

```
getURL(goToUrl);
```

Comment: Sounds good, but not working. My website now is on localhost and the external.txt is on the same folder as swf. Maybe I did not understand. Is this the final code? http://jsfiddle.net/Q5Bzj/5/

Comment: It's working on localhost if I make the path to external file like (http://localhost/external.txt) and on direct html if I place the url like (external.txt). This is strange, but I think will work! Thank you!